# Mortgage loan predictive analysis

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, prediction, pattern-recognition, finance

I have hundreds of thousands of mortgage loan historic records that look like these 2 examples:

```
CCCCCCCCCCCC33CCCC3CCCCCCMFBBBBM999999999999999999963CM3CCCCCCCCCC
BFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF99999999999963333CC33333333CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
```

Each symbol is a monthly status of a loan: C - current, F - foreclosure, M - modification, 3 - 30 days late, 9 - 90 days late, etc. I'm looking to use a machine learning algorithm that could learn form the data and would be able to predict probabilities of the next month outcomes. Could you point to a subset of approaches that I should look into?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a futile exercise. Forget about it.

If you really want to do something of value, start with reading the existing literature on this subject. It's vast. For instance, you can start with Fabozzi's [MBS handbook](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071460748) or Salomon' [red book](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0471385875.html). There are many books and tons of articles, e.g. [this one](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/asmb.827/abstract) with Markov chains.

I'll give you an example to show why your approach is doomed. Let's say you've got IO HELOC, and that you had a fixed payment period ending soon, and that interest rates may (or may not) rise, in this case you're going (or not going) to experience a payment shock. This will have a significant impact on your C->3 transition probability, and eventually on C->F. This payment shock is quite predictable, at least we know when exactly it may or may not happen. If you don't account for these things, your machine learning thing will be garbage.

Comment: I understand this, I was thinking that this can be only a part of my model. I would exclude periods of systemic shocks from the data. It's interesting to see if, isolated from macro events, borrowers can be scored based on their past performance alone (at least to some extent). This is more like a science project.

Comment: Yes, the past performance matters. If you look at mortgage literature you'll find concepts like "burnout": the borrower could but didn't refinance the loan in the recent past for some reason. This borrower will be less likely to respond to prepay incentives, i.e. C->PayOff should be less sensitive to interest rates. If the borrower was delinquent in the past, he will be more likely to be non-current in the future etc. The reason is that there are some non-observable and observable borrower attributes that are persistent.